# MySQL/PHP How would I insert an row into mysql and increase all the auto incremented fields below by 1

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

say i have a table like so:

```
id|name  |
----------
1 |fred  |
2 |jim   |
3 |tracy |
4 |stacy |
```

"id" is the primary index with auto increment.

I would like to add a row below "#2 - jim". I'll call this new row "john".

How could I insert "john" below "jim" so john had the "id" of 3 and all the id's of the names below "john" would go up by 1?

e.g.

```
id|name  |
----------
1 |fred  |
2 |jim   |
3 |john  |
4 |tracy |
5 |stacy |
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You should use something other than the id if you want this for sorting.  If you want to track the most recent entry, add a column with a timestamp and then use ORDER BY DESC to find the most recent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command will add +1 to everyone's id after jim.

```
UPDATE your_table SET id=id+1 WHERE id>2;
```

This command will insert a row just after jim.

```
INSERT INTO your_table(id,name) VALUES(3,'john');
```

It is a very bad idea to change the primary key value. If your table has relationships with other tables, there will be consisitency issue. Let's say it is customer table and there is an order table. The above idea will make trstacy's orders will be connected to tracy and tracy's john, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the autoincrement directive is intended to work. You would need to use UPDATE to change the row 3 to john, UPDATE to change row 4 to tracy, and INSERT to create new row 5 as stacy. This would be awful if you needed to insert a row after row 5 of a 10,000 record table.

You COULD directly change the id value but that is very bad practice.